# hive: Plan not optimized by CBO

Tags: hive, explain, cbo

I am running a explain plan in hive it gives me below error.
Plan not optimized by CBO. When I checked the logs it says.

2016-03-14 00:37:12,082 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-41]: parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer (CalcitePlanner.java:canCBOHandleAst(392)) - Not invoking CBO because the statement has too few joins

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

What is query that you trying to execute.

See logs for msg :

"parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer: Not invoking CBO because the statement has too few joins"

Follow this :

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/4759/hive-explain-says-plan-not-optimized-by-cbo-due-to.html